# How get actual heights of Google Slides table rows?

Tags: google-slides-api

Using Google Slide API I create a table with two rows, each with one cell.
The first one contains a one line text, the second a two lines text.

Since theirs heights are adjusted on the contents, the second row is displayed higher than the first.

Although when I retrieve the table object through the API each rows have the same height: 381000 EMU.

Is there a way to get the actual size of these rows ?

---

Requests I use to create the table and fill the two cells:

```
[{
    "createTable": {
        "objectId": "tableId",
        "rows": 2,
        "columns": 1,
        "elementProperties": {
            "pageObjectId": "pageId"
        }
    }
}, {
    "insertText": {
        "objectId": "tableId",
        "cellLocation": {
            "columnIndex": 0,
            "rowIndex": 0
        },
        "text": "One line"
    }
}, {
    "insertText": {
        "objectId": "tableId",
        "cellLocation": {
            "columnIndex": 0,
            "rowIndex": 1
        },
        "text": "Two\nlines"
    }
}]
```

Object I get with incorrect row sizes:

```
{
    "size": {
        "width": {
            "magnitude": 3000000,
            "unit": "EMU"
        },
        "height": {
            "magnitude": 3000000,
            "unit": "EMU"
        }
    },
    "table": {
        "tableRows": [{
            "rowHeight": {
                "magnitude": 381000,
                "unit": "EMU"
            },
            "tableRowProperties": {
                "minRowHeight": {
                    "magnitude": 381000,
                    "unit": "EMU"
                }
            }
        }, {
            "rowHeight": {
                "magnitude": 381000,
                "unit": "EMU"
            },
            "tableRowProperties": {
                "minRowHeight": {
                    "magnitude": 381000,
                    "unit": "EMU"
                }
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

Note: table sizes also are incorrects.